# LuaTeX renames the .log, .aux, etc

Tags: pdftex, luatex

When I ran LuaTeX on my resume, it renamed all the files produced from pdfing the file.  This is the first time it has every done this.  The file was called resume and it renamed the pdf `texput.pdf`.  Has anyone experienced this before?

When I ran LuaTeX a few months back on my resume, this wasn't the case.

Tex file as requested:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Font size - 10pt, 11pt or 12pt                      
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry} % Document margins             

\usepackage{marvosym} % Required for symbols in the colored box                     
\usepackage{ifsym} % Required for symbols in the colored box                        

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors      

% Fonts and tweaks for XeLaTeX                                                      
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{inconsolata} % Main document font                   
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Kurier}
% Font for your name at the top                                                     
%\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}       

% Colors for links, text and headings                                               
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{506266} % Blue-gray color for links                   
\definecolor{shade}{HTML}{F5DD9D} % Peach color for the contact information box     
\definecolor{text1}{HTML}{2b2b2b} % Main document font color, off-black             
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{701112} % Dark red color for headings                  
% Other color palettes: shade=B9D7D9 and linkcolor=A40000; shade=D4D7FE and         
% linkcolor=FF0080                                                                  

\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=linkcolor, linkcolor=linkcolor}
% Set up links and colors                                                           

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Headers and footers can be added with the \lhead{} \rhead{} \lfoot{} \rfoot{}     
% commands                                                                          
% Example footer:                                                                   
%\rfoot{\color{headings} {\sffamily Last update: \today}. Typeset with XeLaTeX}     

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Get rid of the default rule in the header      

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \section's                           

% Format of the section titles                                                      
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt} % Spacing around titles                      

\begin{document}

\color{text1} % Sets the default text color for the whole document to the color     
% defined as 'text1'                                                                

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 
%       TITLE                                                                       
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\par{\centering{\sffamily\Huge Name Here}\\ % Your name                          
%{\color{headings}\fontspec[Variant = 2]{Arial}                                     
% Curriculum {Vit\fontspec[Variant = 3]{Arial}\ae}\\[15pt]\par}                     


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} % Start the left-hand side of the page           
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment                                                  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 
%       WORK EXPERIENCE                                                             
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\section{Work Experience}

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% WORK EXPERIENCE 1                                                                 
%------------------------------------------------  
{\raggedleft\textsc{Current, from March 19, 2012}\par}

{\raggedright\large classified\\
\textit{xxxxxxx}\\[5pt]}

\normalsize{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% WORK EXPERIENCE 2                                                                 
%------------------------------------------------                                   

{\raggedleft\textsc{Current, from January 2013}\par}

{\raggedright\large Grader for Continuum Mechanics, ME336\\
\textit{University of Vermont}\\[5pt]}

\normalsize{Grade the homework for Continuum Mechanics as well as ran one review
session.}\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% WORK EXPERIENCE 3                                                                 
%------------------------------------------------      

{\raggedleft\textsc{December 2011, from May 2011}\par}

{\raggedright\large Graduate Teaching Assistant\\
\textit{Florida Atlantic University}\\[5pt]}

\normalsize{Selected as teaching assistant for Engineering Calculus 1.
Led review session prior to tests and held office hours to help students with
their homework.
Tutored in the math tutor lab for 10 hours a week.}\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% WORK EXPERIENCE 4                                                                 
%------------------------------------------------                                   

{\raggedleft\textsc{October 2009, from June 2008\\                                  
August 2010, from June 2010}\par}

{\raggedright\large Intern\\
\textit{Merrill Lynch}\\[5pt]}

\normalsize{Analyzed the IRS 5500 Form in order to find a competitive advantage
to market to prospective business clients.
Set up appoints for new business acquisitions in the 401(k) market.}\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% WORK EXPERIENCE 5                                                                 
%------------------------------------------------                                   
{\raggedleft\textsc{May 2007, from June 2006}\par}

{\raggedright\large Club Mate\\
\textit{Pacific Islands Club, Guam}\\[5pt]}

\normalsize{Selected by the Guam Visitor's Bureau to attend the international
travel fair in Taipei, Taiwan for one week.
Passed intermediate speaking test in both Japanese and Korean administered by
representative of the University of Guam.
Multi duty lifeguard, taught windsurfing, sailing, kayaking, and snorkeling.}\\

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\end{minipage} % End the left-hand side of the page                                 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth} % Start the right-hand side of the page         
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment                                                  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 
%       COLORED BOX                                                                 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\colorbox{shade}{\textcolor{text1}{
\begin{tabular}{c|p{7cm}}
\raisebox{-4pt}{\textifsymbol{18}} & xxx Woodhaven Dr., Unit xxxx,
White River, Nowhere, 99999 \\
% Address                                                                           
\raisebox{-3pt}{\Mobilefone} & +1 (727) xxx xxxx \\ % Phone number  
\raisebox{-1pt}{\Letter} & \href{mailto:xxxxx.xxxx@uvm.edu}
{xxxxx.xxxxx@uvm.edu} \\ % Email address                                           
\end{tabular}
}
}\\[10pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 
%       EDUCATION                                                                   
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
% Start a table with two columns, one for dates and one for qualifications          

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% EDUCATION 1                                                                       
%------------------------------------------------                                   

2012 -- \textsc{Present} & \textbf{Master of Science} \\
& \textsc{Mechanical Engineering} \\
& \textit{The University of Vermont}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% EDUCATION 2                                                                       
%------------------------------------------------                                   

2011 & \textbf{Master of Science Candidate} \\
& \textsc{Mathematics} \\
& \textit{Florida Atlantic University}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------                                   
% EDUCATION 3                                                                       
%------------------------------------------------                                   

2011 & \textbf{Bachelor of Science}\\
& \textsc{Mathematics, Finance} \\
& \textit{The University of Tampa}                                                                                                             
\end{tabular}\\[10pt]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 
%       COMPUTER SKILLS                                                             
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                     

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic Knowledge
& \textsc{Matlab}, Python,\\
& Linux, Vim\\
& \\
Intermediate Knowledge
& \textsc{Mathematica},  \LaTeX,\\
& Microsoft Windows, Emacs
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
%       EXTRACURRICULAR                                                             
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\section{Extracurricular}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Societies}
& Pi Mu Epsilon\\
& Phi Theta Kappa\\
& Florida Engineering Society\\
& Shotokan Karate
\end{tabular}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                                                                 

\end{minipage} % End right-hand side of the page                                    

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the default name that TeX (including classic tex) uses if needs to start writing the dvi (or pdf) file before it has seen an input file which has set `\jobname`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why would this happen now when it has never happened before?  Can I stop this?

Comment: @dustin You have probably used iniTeX, not virTeX. Have you got formats (i.e. proper files with .fmt extension)? Could you post your .log file here?

Comment: Are you perhaps compiling from Emacs with AUCTeX?

Comment: @egreg yes but I have done this before without this issue.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I have no idea what initex or virtex is so I don't think I have used either.

Comment: @dustin If I remember correctly, there were problems of this kind after some update, so the method used by default by AUCTeX produced the issue.

Comment: @egreg do I need to use a different AUCTeX version or do something else?  I am on the latest version so that may be the problem?

Comment: @dustin But we know. Hence a .log file would be helpful. However it seems that egreg have already found a solution.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I added the log file but I had to remove half of it since it was too big.  Hopeful I didn't remove any key data.

Comment: @dustin The.log file says that you have LuaTeX format, but somewhere there is unproper grouping. Probably your resume2013.tex (well, non-working subfile of it) would be useful now.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I cant add anything more to the OP since I used the max allowable output adding the log file.

Comment: @dustin And what about removing the log file now and replacing it by your .tex file?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke done.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98063/15925

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem with this in my `.emacs` file (actually `Preferences.el` as I use Aquamacs):

```
'(TeX-engine-alist (quote ((luatex "LuaTeX" "luatex --jobname='%s'"
                                   "lualatex --synctex=1
                                   --jobname='%s'" "luatex"))))
```

Comment: I put your answer in my `.emacs` file, but when I compiled the file, it created the `texput.` files again.

Comment: I moved the placement of into my custom variables and now I think I need to add write18 to it. `Running 'LaTeX' on 'resume2013' with ''lualatex --synctex=1
                                   --jobname='resume2013' --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" resume2013.tex''
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012052410 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**` Then the compiling hangs.  How can I enable write18?  Just add `--write-enable`? If so, where?

Comment: @dustin: You quite certainly do not need to enable write18. Your problem is either due to the way you are calling lualatex (e.g. the `\input` could be the problem) or the format itself - I remember vagely a discussion in one of the mailing list.